# What is the best approach to persist varying data (in multiple formats) into a common db table?

Tags: java, design-patterns, csv

I have data available to me in CSV file. Each CSV is different from another i.e. column names are different. For example in FileA unique identifier is called ID but in FileB it is called UID. Similarly, in FileA amount is called AMT but in FileB it is called CUST_AMT. The meaning is same but column names are different.

I want to create a general solution for saving this varying data from CSV files into a DB table. The solution must take into consideration additional formats that may become available in future.

Is there a best approach for such a scenario?

Comment: Do you have access to process the data before saving it to DB?

Comment: Yes, I have access and full control over the flow from the point CSV file is available to persisting it in db

Comment: and can the columns order, value format be different as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem. But I think the easiest might be to generate a mapping from each input file format to a combined row format. You could create a configuration file that has column name to database field name mappings, and create a program that, given a CSV and a mapping file, can insert all the data into the database.

However, you would still have to alter the table for every new column you want to add.

More design work would require more details on how the data will be used after it enters the database.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the "Chain of responsibility" pattern at the start of the execution. So you read the header and let the chain of responsibility get the appropriate parser for that file.

Code could look like this:

```
interface Parser {
  // returns true if this parser recognizes this format.
  boolean accept(String fileHeader);

  // Each parser can convert a line in the file into insert parameters to be 
  // used with PreparedStatement
  Object[] getInsertParameters(String row);
}
```

This allows you to add new file formats by adding a new Parser object to the chain.

You would first initialize the Chain as follows:

```
List<Parser> parserChain = new ArrayList<Parser>();
parserChain.add(new ParserImplA());
parserChain.add(new ParserImplB());
parserChain.add(new ParserImplB());
....
```

Then you will use it as follows:

```
 // read the header row from file
 Parser getParser (String header) {
    for (Parser parser: parserChain) {
        if (parser.accept(header) 
            return parser;
        }
     throw new Exception("Unrecognized format!");
}
```

Then you can create a prepared statement for inserting a row into the table.
Processing each row of file would be :

```
preparedStatement.execute(parser.getInsertParameters(row));
```